# Using ReaderT based Client wrapper with Servant client

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, servant

I'm trying to extend servant's `ClientM` monad with additional `Token` parameter that I will use to call REST resource.

```
type TClient a = ReaderT Token ClientM a
```

Then I have the following defined for servant pattern matching

```
get :: Token -> ClientM Text
post :: Token -> Int -> ClientM Text
get :<|> post = client (Proxy :: Proxy MyAPI)
```

Now my extended client comes to play. This is how I use it:

```
getT :: TClient Text
getT = undefined -- implementation to extract token and call 'get'

postT :: Int -> TClient Text
portT = undefined -- implementation to extract token and call 'post'

queries :: TClient Text
queries = do
    text1 <- postT 5
    text2 <- getT
    return (text1 ++ text2)

--| runReaderT and then runClientM
runTClient :: Token -> TClient a -> ClientEnv -> IO (Either ServantError a)
runTClient token tcm env = runClientM (runReaderT tcm token) env
```

Question is how to implement `getT` and `postT` functions the better way.

*I will post my current solution, but hopefully more experienced haskellers here can suggest better one*

Answer (score 1):

Following example with IO at the bottom of the page [Control Monad Reader](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html) I had to implement function to lift `ReaderT`

```
liftReaderT :: m a -> ReaderT r m a
liftReaderT m = ReaderT (const m)
```

So then I can have verbose implementation like this:

```
getT :: TClient Text
getT = do
    t <- ask
    liftReaderT $ get t
```

Answer (score 1):

`ReaderT r` is an instance of [`MonadTrans`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans), so you can just use `lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a`. Specialised to the types in question, that's `lift :: ClientM a -> ReaderT Token ClientM a`.

```
getT :: Int -> TClient Text
getT = lift . get

postT :: Int -> TClient Text
postT = lift . post
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Doing just `lift get` I got `Couldn't match expected type 'ClientM Text' with actual type 'Token -> ClientM Text'` so I had to do `ask >>= \t -> lift $ get t`...

Comment: @klappvisor My mistake, that should read `lift . get`. I'll fix the answer

Comment: for `get :: Token -> ClientM Text` I have to read `Token` in `getT` and pass it to `get`. at the moment for `lift . get` I have got `Couldn't match type 'Token -> t0 ClientM Text' with 'ReaderT Token ClientM Text'`